# I want to add a group of buttons to the map (menu)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to add a group of buttons to the map (google map api v3). how to do it please

Comment: You should check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls

Comment: Thanks for link but it wasn't really very clear to me :(

Comment: You haven't shared your work, you need an explanation to understand and Google has already have an excellent documentation about this. That's all I can do. I think you should try more, in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom it's very clear. If you still can't get it, you should get back and look at the basics more.

Comment: well received thank you bro :)